# Print index of biggest element

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic, interactive

Peter has N balls, numbered 1 through N.

No two balls weigh the same. You want to find the heaviest ball but you do not know which one it is and Peter does not want to just give it to you. Therefore, he decided to play a game with you.

You may ask Peter at most Q=4+N/2 questions. In each question, you must give Peter the numbers of five distinct balls and Peter tells you the numbers of the 3-rd and 4-th heaviest of these balls. Find the number of the heaviest ball!

**Interaction:**
First, you should read a line containing a single integer T denoting the number of test cases.
For each test case, you should start by reading a line containing a single integer N.
To ask a question, you should print a line containing the character '?', a space and five space-separated integers i1, i2, i3, i4 and i5: the numbers of five distinct balls (in any order).

Then, you must read a line containing two space-separated integers: the numbers of the 3-rd and 4-th heaviest balls.

To finish solving a test case, print a line containing the character '!', a space and an integer im: the number of the heaviest ball (1≤im≤N).

Don't forget to flush the output after printing each line!

**Constraints:**

- 1≤T≤1,000
- 6≤N≤100

**Example:**

```
You               Grader
                  1
                  6
? 1 2 3 4 5
                  3 4
? 1 2 3 4 6
                  3 4
? 1 2 3 5 6
                  3 5
? 1 2 4 5 6
                  4 5
? 1 3 4 5 6
                  4 5
? 2 3 4 5 6
                  4 5
! 6
```

**Explanation:**

The balls are sorted in descending order of weight.

This is a paraphrasing of a problem in a codechef contest, paraphrased because original problem statement was not very clear.

Here is my code(for n>6):

I know it isn't very efficient,I have been editing it trying to find the error

(C++)

Comment: Note sure I understand the problem you are having - could you clarify what the exact error is you are seeing? What input data are you using, what's the expected output, what's the actual?

Comment: @codeling That's the problem. Codechef doesn't provide test cases, I tried making some of my own test cases and it worked fine.

Comment: Then please state that clearly in the question - that codechef reports your code to be incorrect, while you have tested it with x, y, and z and it provided the expected result of a, b, and c....

Comment: `fflush( stdout )` (C) --> `<< std::flush` (C++). Also, [`<algorithm>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). [This talk from CppCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2olsGf6JIkU) gives a nice intro into what the standard library can do for you...

Comment: Just doing [`std::cout << std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) flushes as well...

Answer (score 1):

The whole issue boils down to finding greatest element of six, you have `4 + 6/2 = 7` tries for. For more than six elements, with every try, you sort out two of them (which is what you did already), so that's where the formula `4 + N/2` comes from...

First five tests (actually, all we need/can do) will be:

```
(6) 12345  34   // one of 1235 must be heavier than 34
(5) 12346  34   // one of 1236 must be heavier than 34
(4) 12356  35   // ...
(3) 12456  45
(2) 13456  45
(1) 23456  45
```

For now we can be sure that 3, 4, and 5 cannot be heaviest, remaining 1, 2, 6

Now let's have a close look:

Removing 5 or 6 from the set results twice in same 3rd and 4th.
Removing 4 from the set results results in a 3rd and 4th combination only occurring once.
Removing 1, 2, or 3 from the set results three times in same 3rd and 4th.

What we now are interested in are exactly these two sets with same 3rd and 4th exactly occurring twice:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 1, 2, 3, 4, 6. We know from these that either 5 or 6 must be greatest; combined with very first observation (3, 4, 5 excluded), only 6 remains.

Actually, we even know more:

The one not selected (5) from the set of two occurrences (5, 6) is second heaviest, the single occurrence of 3rd/4th (4) reveals third heaviest, and the remaining one (3) from the initially excluded ones (3, 4, 5) is fourth heaviest.

Solely 5th and 6th cannot be distinguished...

***Edit:*** Filtering the surplus values:

You might simplify your code a bit:

```
int t;
std::cin >> t;
while(t--) // sparse you another variable...
{
    int n = 12;
    --n; // exclude highest value!
    int ar[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // just *always* maintain the values in the array...
    // note: the array is one larger as you had initially!
    for (int i = 6; i < n; i = i + 2) // prefer local scope for i!
    //           ^ can start at a later point of time, we'll be replacing AFTERWARDS
    {
        std::cout << '?';
        for(auto a : ar)            // loop might or not be more elegant
            std::cout << '\t' << a; // performance: most likely, compiler unrolls
                                    // anyway...
        std::cout << std::endl;
        int x, y; // scope as local as possible...
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        // OK, I don't want to modify the loop variable, so I now use a duplicate...
        int ii = i;
        for(auto& a : ar) // I like the range based for loops...
        //      ^ reference this time is important, though!
        {
            if(a == x || a == y)
                a = ii++;
        }
    }
    if((n & 1) == 0)
    {
        // for even n, we have done one test too few!
        // instead of duplicating the code, you might write a common function for...
        std::cout << '?';
        for(auto a : ar)
            std::cout << '\t' << a;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        int x, y; // scope as local as possible...
        std::cin >> x >> y;

        for(auto& a : ar)
        {
            if(a == x || a == y)
            {
                a = n;
                break; // just replace one!!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code as above will produce 5 elements to check. Remember that we excluded the highest value(`--n;`)? We'll now revert:

```
++n;
```

`n` now will be the 6th value to be checked, in addition to the five ones remaining in the array (if you don't like incrementing and decrementing, you can alternatively maintain two variables, of course). You can use `std::swap` to exchange one value of the array after another.

Side note: I personally would prefer the more C++-like `std::array<int, 5> ar({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});` instead of the raw array, but that's not much of an issue. It would make passing the array to function easier, though, if you make one from the duplicate code:

```
void f(std::array<int, 5> const& ar); // or non-const, if you want to replace inside, too
// or in more generic form:
template <size_t N>
void f(std::array<int, N> const& ar);

// vs.:

void f(int const(&ar)[5]);
// the more generic form:
template <size_t N>
void f(int const(&ar)[N]);
// or classical (and better known) pointer variant:
void f(int const* ar, size_t length);
```

Final side notes:

1. You do not check the streams after user input. If user enters anything invlid, this will break your streams and thus the whole code. It might not be necessary in this specific case, but in general, it would be quite a good idea to get used to right from the start (something like `if(!cin >> x >> y) { /* appropriate error handling */ }`), maybe even check valid range afterwards (e. g. error, if `x` and `y` are equal or do not match exactly one value in array – for the latter, we'd have to pay attention on not matching against an already replaced value, though).
2. As far as I understood the question, negative values are meaningless, thus I would (consistently) prefer `unsigned int` as data type. But that's not much of an issue, so decide you on your own...

Comment: My code doesn't work for n<7,I mentioned it in the question..However for n>6,after repeatedly removing 3rd and 4th largest values,We know we have the 2 lightest and the heaviest elements remaining in the array.So by checking with 4 random weights between these 3, we can infer from the output the heaviest just from 2 tests. We take 1 element from the array and 4 random values and test twice,if the output doesn't change, the 2 array elements we tried the tests for must be the 2 smallest,if the output shifts left, the array element in the second test must be heaviest.

Comment: What do you mean for even n we have done 1 test too few? Why?

Comment: @JustinCase Lets consider starting condition `n == 5` will not enter the loop at all (we have 6 numbers, remember the initial `--i`!). However, for `n == 6`, the loop is not entered *either*, but we have 7 numbers and need to exclude one. For larger n, the problem remains unchanged due to the `i += 2`, e. g. `i < n` with `i == 8` will result in `false` for both `n == 7` and `n == 8`!